# Magento2: Reset specific indexer by cronjob

Tags: magento2, indexer, cronjobs

Sometimes the indexer `catalog_product_category` doesn't automatically run when assigning new products to a category, so products aren't displayed at the shop. I've to manually reset this indexer in the shell before it's reindexed and the products are displayed at new assigned category.

I've tried a lot of things and worked through many forums, but no solution yet. So I want to try the following:

Reset the indexer `catalog_product_category` every night by a cronjob. However, I'm unable to figure out the right cronjob command to reset the indexer. Does anyone know this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

> /usr/local/bin/php /home/abc/domains/domain.nl/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category